Crystal Reports - Display text in footer if one detail line items condition is true else suppress
I'll like to display a text in the report's footer if a line item meets a specific condition, if it does not then the footer's text should suppress.  I have it working if there's just one line item, however, if there are two or more with meeting a "true" condition and a "false" then the text still suppresses. If I have 4 line items and just one meets the condition then the report's text should display.  I created a header variable and a detail line's variable, on the footer I'm testing if the variable = true, however, if three of the line items = true but just one = false the text suppresses.
I created a header formula field setting variable sampleflag to false
I created a Detail formula field that sets sampleflag variable to true if an inventory item's field has a specific value
On the report footer I have a text box with a Suppress formula based on sampleflag = False

Make sure the detail-level formula does NOT set that variable to False if the condition doesn't apply.
It should only change the variable value if the condition is true.
If that was not the issue, debug by creating a detail-level formula that shows the value of the variable.
